# Mysql append data to fields?

Tags: mysql, append, concatenation

I have a table which contains 3 columns, `fname` `Lname` and `description`. I want to take the values of `Fname` and `Lname` and append them to `description` (Move this data to the end of the description field without overwriting the current info in the field). Is this possible with MySQL at all?

Comment: are you looking for the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Please update function as per req...and concatination of string :
Here Concat function is used for concat string..:
```

> update table_name set description = CONCAT(description,'
>   ',fname,' ',Lname);

Comment: Exactly hat i was looking thanks for pointing out the function i needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
update your_table_name set description = CONCAT(description,' ', fname,' ',Lname);
```

Comment: thanks for the review :) i did not put any whitespace since the question did not mention them... but it's ok, i think that's what he meant.